# How to remove default dropdown Select option in Wordpress Contact Form Manager plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the [Wordpress Contact Form Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-manager/) plugin. If I set a dropdown's element `Default drop down value` to some value that value does appears selected as I've set it. The problem is when I click on the dropdown to expand it, the additional `Select` option appears as shown on the image, and I can't seem to find where could I customize this. I went through their FAQ and googled but no help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems the option to edit this really doesn't exist via the plugin admin panel and in order to remove the additional `Select` option you have to edit the `create-contact-form.php` starting on line `1006` and comment the code out:

```
if($formElementDetail->client_view_multi_select_drop_down != 1){
    //$replace = $replace.'<option value="">Select</option>';
}
```

You can of course comment (or remove) the whole `if` case. Hope this will help someone.